# Can I use labeled data and rule-based matching for multiclass text classification with Spacy?

Tags: spacy

I have some labeled data (down to 1000) (shape: text, category ) and up to 10k unlabeled data. I want to use the rules-based matching linguistic tool of Spacy to define for every category a pattern. After this, I would like to train a new model using the rules and the data that I've had labeled. It is this possible? I've seen some tutorial on youtube* which does something similar, but they use the labeled data to determine if a sentence contains some entity. On the other hand, I want to put a label on an entire paragraph.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqOJU1-_Fi0

Comment: Can you share example data, and share what you have written with examples?

Comment: I cannot share real examples, but I've written some basic examples which follow the pattern of my data. The training data would look lie this: {text: 'This is an example of a text that talks about apples.',
category: 'apples'}
{text: 'This is an example of a text that talks about oranges',
category: 'oranges'}
The patterns would look like this

applePattern = [{"LOWER": "apple"}, {"POS": "NOUN"}]
orangePattern =  [{"LOWER": "orange"}, {"POS": "NOUN"}]